# Use data from dataframe Y to rename columns in data frame X with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe Y that looks something like this:

```
Y = data.frame(names=as.factor(c("name1", "name2")), other=c(1,2))
```

and a dataframe X that looks something like this:

```
X = data.frame(col1=c(1,0,1,1),col2=c(0,0,0,1), col3=c(0,0,0,1))
```

I want to rename the columns of X.

```
X = data.frame(name1=c(1,0,1,1),name2=c(0,0,0,1), col3=c(0,0,0,1))
```

I tried the following, but it does not work

```
library(dplyr)
X = X %>% rename(as.character(Y$names[[1]]) = col1)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: From what I can gather, you would like to rename the columns based on the values in column 1 of Y. Might be a good idea to include your final data.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
colnames(X)<-Y$names
```

Comment: What if X has many columns, and I want to set the names only for coumns n to m? For my example, only for column 1. I tried colnames(X[,1])<-Y$names[1] but it does not work :_(

Comment: This does the trick for my modified example. colnames(X)[1:2]<-as.character(Y$names[1])